# Webpack dev server to Node/IIS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iis, webpack

I made an React App  and currently i'm using webpack dev server to host it locally.
I need now to deploy and have this app run as a service in a Windows Server in order to be able to close the Windows Session and still have the app running.

Now, i don't really know how webpack dev server works... i have worked on NodeJS project and just by running "node {file}" the server was running and with "forever" extension it ran as a service.

How can i make this app run as a service?

The way i host my app locally is by using "npm start" which according to the package.json runs a webpack-dev-server.

package.json (just a part):

```
  "scripts": {
"start": "webpack-dev-server --hot --open",
"lint": "eslint src"  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically your Front end files (if they've NOT server side code) are `static` files (`HTML / CSS/ IMAGES/ and so on`) .. so if they're `ONLY STATIC FILES and ASSETS` . .can be deployed on every server ... I USUALLY use WEBPACK DEV-SERVER for developing purpose and then deploy them on IIS ..

Just 2 things:

```
1 -BE SURE to SET the default page on IIS on  Index.html (via Web.Config)

2 - BE SURE to HAVE INSTALLED IIS REWRITE MODULE (to do a redirect to index.html page)
```

Hope it helps you ...

Comment: The webpack generates a "bundle.js" as the app itself. This is what confuses me... i don't have a "point of entry" or something... just a ".js" file. How should i serve it?

Comment: ok .. check if your index.html has a <script src="bunde.js"></script> ..if so try to deploy the index.html (set it as default page on iis) and laso your bundle.js file .. + assets folder if you have one with images and so on

Comment: So i tried doing this but i get the same result that when i just run the "index.html" file. It links correctly the "bundle.js" but throws an error inside itself because of "Invalid or unexpected token". 

The error message can be seen at:
https://ibb.co/kj38sw
https://ibb.co/dfW6eb

If i run this using "webpack-dev-server", the app launches successfully.

Comment: It does. So what would be the difference between running webpack-web-server and running webpack and open the "index.html" with the "bundle.js" generated?

Comment: i think the difference is the builiding ...cause the dev use the dev SETTINGS .. other build use the prod mode

Comment: That was it. I was using different configurations for dev and prod... i've just copy-pasted all my dev config into prod and worked like charm. I will clear all the configs that should not be on prod and i'm ready to go. Thank you very much, federico!!!

Comment: very happy to helped ypu

Answer (score 0):

Serve your files as static pages from your Node/IIS server.

Comment: It's my first React app, and my first time with webpack. If i run "webpack", it generates a "bundle.js" as result. How can i serve that bundle? Or i should not use the bundle?